# How can I resize the plot in order to be used in R Markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created the attached plot using the mentioned code, however, the height of the whole plot looks a bit large and the blank area between the plot and the legend does not seem suitable.

I want to resize the plot in order to use it later in R Markdown presentation. I've seen some posts about resizing the plots but they have all been about resizing the plot for saving purposes. I want to get a plot that looks similar to the one created by Urban Institute Style Guide.

```
ggplot(top_five, aes(x= Year, y = Production, fill = Country)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#375E97", "#FB6542", "#FFBB00", "#3F681C", "#98DBC6")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30000), breaks = c(0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000), labels = scales::comma) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "top", 
        legend.key.height = unit(0.8, "lines"), 
        legend.key.width = unit(0.8, "lines"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold")) + 
  labs(title= "Top Five Oil-Producing Countries (2012-2017)", subtitle = "Thousand Barrels Daily", 
       caption = "Source: BP Statistical Review") +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.position=c(0,1),
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.justification=c(0, 1))
```

My Plot

[image: My Plot]

Urban Institute's Plot

[image: Urban Institute's Plot]

Comment: did you mean to set the limits in `scale_y_continuous` to `c(0,30000)`

Comment: You should think about the sizing arguments within the `renderPlot` function in the UI.R file as well as the ggplot2 details within the server.R file. In particular, look at the arguments 'width', 'height' and 'res'. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderPlot.html

Comment: @RichardTelford Not really. I'm happy with the scale (though I made a mistake by putting (0, 30000)). All what I need is to decrease the height of the whole plot in order to get a plot similar to the second one.

Comment: You wanted result is not clear. If you want final result presented in R markdown presentation then please add code/MRE for it. I guess you fill need to modify `fig.asp` in chunk.